# C# ComboBox columns

Tags: c#, combobox

Assuming I have the following text file :

```
100 Rogue   common_mark_job_0018
101 Fighter common_mark_job_0019
102 Kahuna  common_mark_job_0020
103 Spell Singer    common_mark_job_0026
110 Champion    common_mark_job_0022
111 Archer  common_mark_job_0023
112 Druid   common_mark_job_0024
113 Battle Kahuna   common_mark_job_0031
114 Evoker  common_mark_job_0032
120 Berserker   common_mark_job_0027
121 Marksman    common_mark_job_0029
122 Magus   common_mark_job_0028
123 War Kahuna  common_mark_job_0030
124 Beast Master    common_mark_job_ga_2summon01
200 Guide   common_mark_job_0033
201 Holy Warrior    common_mark_job_0002
202 Cleric  common_mark_job_0003
203 Breeder common_mark_job_0004
210 Knight  common_mark_job_0034
211 Soldier common_mark_job_0035
212 Bishop  common_mark_job_0006
213 Priest  common_mark_job_0007
214 Soul Breeder    common_mark_job_0009
220 Templar common_mark_job_0005
221 Mercenary   common_mark_job_de_2summon01
222 Cardinal    common_mark_job_0008
223 Oracle  common_mark_job_0037
224 Master Breeder  common_mark_job_0039
300 Stepper common_mark_job_0040
301 Strider common_mark_job_0010
302 Dark Magician   common_mark_job_0011
303 Sorcerer    common_mark_job_0012
310 Assassin    common_mark_job_0013
311 Shadow Hunter   common_mark_job_0014
312 Chaos Magician  common_mark_job_0015
313 Warlock common_mark_job_0016
314 Battle Summoner common_mark_job_0017
320 Slayer  common_mark_job_0041
321 Deadeye common_mark_job_0042
322 Void Mage   common_mark_job_0043
323 Corruptor   common_mark_job_0044
324 Overlord    common_mark_job_0045
```

I'm trying to load it (the text above) on my ComboBoxEdit (should be same as simple ComboBox) , I'm doing that either on Form1_Load or on the ComboBoxEdit On_click and they both works just fine .

```
  {

        if (comboBoxEdit2.Text != string.Empty)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            ComboBoxItemCollection coll = comboBoxEdit2.Properties.Items;
            coll.BeginUpdate();
            try
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Application.StartupPath + "/MyLists.dll");
                System.Resources.ResourceManager resourcemanager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("ClassLibrary1.Properties.Resources", assembly);

                string[] strArrays15 = resourcemanager.GetString("JobList").Split('\n');

                for (int row = 0; row < strArrays15.Length; row++)
                {
                    columns = strArrays15[row].Split('\t');
                    //  comboBoxEdit2.Items.Add(columns[1]);
                    coll.Add(columns[1]);

                }
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

As you can see I'm only loading the second cell which means the names "Rogue" , "Fighter" etc ... 
Now on SelectedIndexChanged I'm doing this :

```
private void comboBoxEdit2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureEdit3.Image = new Bitmap(Application.StartupPath + "/jpg/" + columns[2].ToString() + ".jpg");
    }
```

It's not working and the PictureBox image is only showing the last line image (not matter what Item I choose from the ComboBox I choose , the image of the last line shows for all cases) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `columns` in your code currently holds only a row in every iteration of your `for` loop. So every time the `for` loop is completely executed, the `columns` variable will hold only the last processed row, that's why you only get the last picture. After you execute the `for` loop in you code, the `columns` variable will hold this data (corresponding to the last line in you file):

```
columns[0] = "324"
columns[1] = "Overlord"
columns[2] = "common_mark_job_0045"
```

So every time the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler is called, `columns[2].ToString()` will always return `"common_mark_job_0045"`. What you want is a data structure like this, so that you can retrieve the right image for each row (and not only for the last row as before):

```
// Columns of first row
columns[0][0] = "110"
columns[0][1] = "Champion"
columns[0][2] = "common_mark_job_0022"

// Columns of second row
columns[1][0] = "111"
columns[1][1] = "Archer"
columns[1][2] = "common_mark_job_0023"
```

To make the code work, you should save the columns for each row in you file, something like this:

```
string[][] columns;

...

string[] strArrays15 = resourcemanager.GetString("JobList").Split('\n');
columns = new string[strArrays15.Length][];

for (int row = 0; row < strArrays15.Length; row++)
{
    columns[row] = strArrays15[row].Split('\t');
    //  comboBoxEdit2.Items.Add(columns[row][1]);
    coll.Add(columns[row][1]);
}
```

Then, when the user changes the selected item in the combobox, use this event handler to retrieve the right image:

```
private void comboBoxEdit2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureEdit3.Image = new Bitmap(Application.StartupPath + "/jpg/" +
                         columns[comboBoxEdit2.SelectedIndex][2].ToString() + ".jpg");
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer , when I debug I'm having an issue on the line 277 which means the "coll.Add(columns[row][1]);" code .

Comment: What is the error exactly? Have you changed the `columns` variable type to `string[][]`?

Comment: I'm not sure why there is two[] [] on the second line (on code you posted) because it wouldn't amke sense .
Other then that ,I declared columns as  string[] columns;  on the top of my application yes . and the error is this :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Rappelz ~~ GM Tool.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Please declare columns as `string[][] columns;` and then use the code I posted and it should work. I'll edit my answer to explain why you should use `string[][]` instead of `string[]`.

Comment: Ooh right well now it's working for the loading , however when I chane the Item on the ComboBox , picture doesn't show and I'm having this error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: What is the value of `Application.StartupPath + "/jpg/" + columns[comboBoxEdit2.SelectedIndex][2].ToString() + ".jpg"` when you get the error?

Comment: I was able to fix it . I repalced "\r" on the path by " " . that was the issue .
thank sfor your help .